# PowerBI Incremental Refresh Parameter

Tags: powerbi

I have a question about PowerBI incremental refresh parameters.
I couldn't understand the role of parameters. How can I define the parameters? Actually I mean is the parameter range important?

Answer (score 3):

Incremental refresh uses two parameters, named RangeStart and RangeEnd (names are case sensitive). When published, the service will automatically change the parameter values, to load only the data added after the last load, e.g. only for the last day.

Incremental refresh isn't designed to support cases where the filtered date column is updated in the source system, only to load newly added rows. If an update is interpreted as an insertion and a deletion, not an actual update, it might work. If the deletion occurs in the historical range and not the incremental range, it won’t get picked up.

To define the parameters with default values, in the Power Query Editor, select Manage Parameters and add their initial values which will filter the initial load. Once published, the parameter values are overridden automatically by the Power BI service.

[image]

With the parameters defined, you can then apply the filter by selecting the Custom Filter menu option for a column.

[image]

Ensure rows are filtered where the column value is after or equal to RangeStart and before RangeEnd. Other filter combinations may result in double counting of rows.

[image]

Verify queries have an equal to (=) on either RangeStart or RangeEnd, but not both. If the equal to (=) exists on both parameters, a row could satisfy the conditions for two partitions, which could lead to duplicate data in the model, i.e. the same order to be loaded in the model twice in two consecutive loads.

For more details see [Incremental refresh in Power BI Premium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-premium-incremental-refresh).

Comment: You said "When published, the service will automatically change the parameter values, to load only the data added after the last load", so what is importance of RangeStart and RangeEnd, for example inital date is 12/29/2010 12:00:00 AM in table, but you entered 12/1/2012 12:00:00 AM as RangeStart, what happens if I use the initial date(12/29/2010) as RangeStart?

Comment: When you set values manually, you will load only those in the initial report, e.g. for the last year. Then you publish the report and setup incremental refresh. On the next load, RangeStart will be set to the previous RangeEnd and RangeEnd will be set to the current time. This way it will load only the newly added rows from the data source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just for clarify for my purpose;
If I want to keep all data in the table and grab only new records with incremental refresh, I need to write Min(date) as RangeStart and Max(date) as RangeEnd, right?
If I write some date in the middle(not min, not max), before that date there won't be any data?

Comment: @ Andrey Nikolov, Thanks a lot!